# ¿Como reducir el tiempo de ejecución de este código en javascript para calcular números amigos?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de buscar números amigos entre los 10000 primeros números.

> Números amigos significa que los divisores de un numero sumados son iguales al otro y entonces son amigos.

En este código no se tienen en cuenta los números iguales.
He conseguido encontrarlos y realizar un código funcional pero cuando lo ejecuto tarda 13min en encontrar los 10000 números.

```
var num1;
var num2;

function divisor (x){
    var suma = 0;

    for(var k=1;k<= Math.floor(x/2) + 1; k++){
        if(x%k ==0){
            suma = suma + k;
        }
    }
    return suma;
}

for(var a = 2; a<10000; a++ ){
    num1 = divisor(a);

    for(var b= a; b<10000; b++){
        num2 = divisor(b);
        if(num1 == b && num2 == a && a<b){
            console.log(a + ' y ' + b + ' son amigos' + '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si al buscar los amigos de `a`, encontramos a `b`, `c`, etc. ¿no sería lógico que al buscar los amigos de `d` , los números anteriormente obtenidos (`eg: a, b, c`) no sean considerados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás haciendo múltiples veces el cáculo de `divisor` que es una función bastante pesada.

En mi solución primero creo un `Objeto` con el cálculo de todos los divisores. Luego con los cálculos ya hechos procedo a buscar amigos.

```js
    console.time();
    
    var num1 = 0;
    var num2 = 10000;
    
    
    const divisor = (x) => {
      let suma = 0;
      
      for(let k=1;k<= Math.floor(x/2) + 1; k++){
        if(x%k ==0){
          suma = suma + k;
        }
      }
      return suma;
    }
    
    /**
     * Make sure input is value
     * num1 < num2
     * num1 < 100000 
     * num2 < 100000
     */
    
    
    /**
     * Create a map with all computed divisor sums
     * {
     *  220: 284,
     *  284: 220
     * }
     */
    
    const array = [1,2,3,4]
    const map = {}
    
    for (let i = num1; i<num2; i++) {
      map[i] = divisor(i)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create new array only with values that find friends
     */
    const friends = Object.keys(map)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    
      const key = parseInt(curr, 10)
      const value = map[key]
    
      if (key === map[value]) {
        delete map[key]
        delete map[value]
        acc.push([key, value])
      }
    
      return acc
    }, [] )
    .filter((friend) => {
      return friend[0] !== friend[1]
    })
    .forEach((friend) => {
      console.log(`Los numeros ${friend[0]} y ${friend[1]} són amigos`)
    })
    
    console.timeEnd()
```

Comment: como se llama la tecnica que aplicastes en la creacion del objeto tipo map? que por cierto no es un [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) debes corregir eso

Comment: te invito a usar Set sera mas rapido, y la tecnica que aplicastes se conoce como [memoización](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: El proceso no se tarda lo que se ejecuta en el código, estas poniendo console.time antes de ejecutar todo, es normal un tan bajo tiempo de ejecución, pero ese no es el tiempo de ejecucion real.

Comment: Set era un typo, en cualquier caso necesitaria un Map, voy a hacer unos tests para ver si mejora el tiempo

Comment: @Riven inicializo el timer al principio del codigo y llamo a timeEnd al final de la ejecución. Que es lo incorrecto?

Comment: No habia visto ese timeEnd del final, pense que console.time funcionaba diferente, tienes razon Borjante, el tiempo no es incorrecto.

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurren dos formas de agilizar el algoritmo.

1. **Cálculo de la suma de divisores**
   Podemos recorrer los números de `1` a `Math.sqrt(x)`, siendo `x` el número del cual queremos la suma de los divisores.
   Sabemos que el divisor **más grande** de `x` será `x / 2`, si `x` es par. De modo que no nos hace falta recorrer los números de `x / 2` a `x`.

```
const calcSumOfDiv = x => {
    // La suma empieza en 1, porque siempre será un divisor.
    let sum = 1;
    // El loop empezará en 2 (para no repetir el 1)
    // Y llegará hasta Math.sqrt(x). Haciendo el cuadrado de i, es lo mismo.
    for (let i = 2; i * i < x; ++i) {
        if (x % i === 0) {
            sum += i;

            // Debemos también contemplar el caso de los mayores
            // por la propiedad conmutativa.
            // Siendo x par, si i = 2, i es divisor y también x / 2.
            // Así que sumamos ambos.
            // Excepto el caso de cuadrados perfectos
            if (x / i !== i) {
                sum += x / i;
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

2. **Almacenamiento de cálculos**
   Por otra parte, como en el algoritmo tenemos dos *loops*, significa que estamos haciendo cálculos de divisores duplicados.

```
for(let a = 2; a < LENGTH; a++) {
    for(let b = a; b < LENGTH; b++) {
        // En la primera iteración del loop interno,
        // La suma de divisores de a ya se ha calculado, pero b = a y se vuelve a calcular para a
    }
    // En la siguiente vuelta, a será a + 1, pero la suma de divisores de a + 1
    // ya la tenemos calculada cuando recorrimos el loop en b.
}
```

Por ello, podemos almacenar los cálculos ya hechos para reaprovecharlos la siguiente vez que vayan a necesitarse. De modo que sólo se calcula la suma de divisores de cada número una única vez.

```
// Aquí guardamos los cálculos. La clave es el número y el valor su suma de divisores
const map = {
    1: 1
};

// Cuando querramos sacar el cálculo, primero vemos si lo tenemos ya.
// Si NO es el caso, lo calculamos y lo guardamos.
const sumOfDiv = x => {
    if (!map[x]) map[x] = calcSumOfDiv(x);
    return map[x];
}
```

Así quedaría el *script* entero.

```
const LENGTH = 10000;

const map = {
    1: 1
};

const calcSumOfDiv = x => {
    let sum = 1;
    for (let i = 2; i * i < x; ++i) {
        if (x % i === 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (x / i !== i) {
                sum += x / i;
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

const sumOfDiv = x => {
    if (!map[x]) map[x] = calcSumOfDiv(x);
    return map[x];
}

const areAmicable = (x, y) =>
    x !== y &&
    sumOfDiv(x) === y &&
    sumOfDiv(y) === x;

for(let a = 2; a < LENGTH; a++) {
    for(let b = a; b < LENGTH; b++) {
        if (areAmicable(a, b)) {
            console.log(`${a} and ${b} are amicables.`);
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado es un poco inmediato.

> 220 and 284 are amicables.
>   1184 and 1210 are amicables.
>   2620 and 2924 are amicables.
>   5020 and 5564 are amicables.
>   6232 and 6368 are amicables.
>   algorithm: 203.038ms

En *200ms*, aproximadamente.

Espero que sirva.